# How can I get form data and add it to an object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am using this form to take some basic information:

```
 <form action="/action_page.php" method="GET" name="clientForm">
        <label for="cname">Client name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="cname" placeholder="client name:" name="cname" required><br>
        <label for="clienturl">URL:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="clienturl" placeholder="url:" name="clienturl" required><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" button (click)="addClient()" >
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
      </form>
```

This is the data i am currently holding:

```
  export const clients = [
    {
      name: 'client1',
      url: "https://www.google.com"
    },
    {
      name: 'client2',
      url: "https://www.yahoo.com"
    },
    {
      name: 'ACB',
      url: "https://www.dailymail.co.uk"
    },
    {
      name: 'client3',
      url: "https://www.youtube.com"
    },
    {

      name: 'client4',
      url: "https://www.nhs.uk"
    },
  ];
```

Then in my component I am struggling to get the data entered into the form and add it as an object to the existing data.

Comment: I suggest start reading https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful. I'll take a look through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the **Reactive Forms / Angular Standard Forms** in your angular app, you can get it...

```
<form [formGroup]="FormName" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
```

in TypeScript:

```
this.FormName.value
```

[For more details, see the official documents](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview)

By using the traditional way, you can add in to the object